# Sort in descending order the array elements that belong to the shaded area

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
 
int **CreateMatrix (int rows, int cols);
void FillMatrix (int **matrix, int rows, int cols);
void OutputMatrix (int **matrix, int rows, int cols);
void SortMatrix (int **matrix, int rows, int cols);
void DellMatrix(int **matrix, int rows);
 
int main(){
 
    srand(time(NULL));
 
    int rows = 9, cols = 9;
 
    int **matrix = CreateMatrix(rows, cols);
    FillMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    cout << "Цикл до сортування: " << endl;
    OutputMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
 
    cout << endl;
    SortMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    cout << "Цикл після сортування: " << endl;
    OutputMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    DellMatrix(matrix, rows);
 
 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
 
 
 
int **CreateMatrix(int rows, int cols){    
 
    int **matrix = new int *[rows];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int [cols];
 
    }
    return matrix;
 
}
 
void FillMatrix(int **matrix, int rows, int cols){
 
    int N = 19; 
 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
 
            matrix[i][j] = N; 
 
        }
    }
 
    for (int i = rows - 1; i > rows / 2 - 1; i--)
    {
        for (int k = cols - 1 - i; k < 1 + i; k++) 
           
        {
            matrix[i][k] = rand() % 100; 
        }
 
 
    }
}
 
void OutputMatrix(int **matrix, int rows, int cols){
 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
 
            cout << setw(5) << matrix[i][j];
 
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
 
void SortMatrix (int **matrix, int rows, int cols){ //selection sort 
 
    int max, maxi;
 
    for (int k = rows - 1; k > rows / 2 - 1; k--) 
    {                                            
        for (int i = cols - 1 - k; i < 1 + k; i++) 
        {
 
            max = matrix[k][i]; 
            maxi = i; 
 
 
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= k; j++)
               
            {
 
                if (matrix[k][j] > max) 
                {
                    max = matrix[k][j]; 
                    maxi = j;           
                }
            }
 
            matrix[k][maxi] = matrix[k][i]; 
            matrix[k][i] = max; 
           
        }
 
    }
}
 
void DellMatrix(int **matrix, int rows){
 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete matrix[i];
    }
    delete[] matrix;
 
}
```

```
Цикл до сортування: 
  19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   19   64   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   64   47   94   19   19   19
  19   19   59    5   54   70    4   19   19
  19   56   21   49   45   17   87   61   19
  48    3    5   33   40   70   84   46   68

Цикл після сортування: 
  19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   19   64   19   19   19   19
  19   19   19   94   64   47   19   19   19
  19   19   70   59   54    5    4   19   19
  19   87   61   56   49   45   21   17   19
  84   70   68   48   46   40   33    5    3
```

[image]

Hi all, Task: The elements in the shaded area are generated randomly. All others = N.
Arrange the elements in the shaded area in descending order.
I did a sort in rows, but I need all elements in general to be sorted in descending order, i.e. at the top the biggest elements, below the smallest.
I can not figure out how to re-do it, hope for your help! Thank you.

Comment: Use an array of `25` `int`, fill in random values, sort it and then fill your `matrix` with one after another of these values.

Comment: @mch, Hello, thank you. But why exactly `25 int`? So, I need to convert two-dimensional array to one-dimensional, sort it and then back it in two-dimensional again?

Comment: `9+7+5+3+1` values. Just create an array, fill it with random numbers, sort it and instead of `matrix[i][k] = rand() % 100;` do `matrix[i][k] = array[index++];`.

Comment: @mch, ok, thank you, i'll try it. But i dont understand where you got `9+7+5+3+1`, sorry xd, explain please.

Comment: @mch, I posted an answer in which I took your tips, but it does not work correctly, look at it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
int NumberOfValues(int cols)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = cols; i > 0; i -=2)
        count += i;
    return count;
}

void FillMatrix(int **matrix, int rows, int cols){

    int N = 19;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = N;
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> random_numbers(NumberOfValues(cols));
    for (auto &i : random_numbers)
        i = rand() % 100;

    std::sort(begin(random_numbers), end(random_numbers));
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = rows - 1; i > rows / 2 - 1; i--)
    {
        for (int k = cols - 1 - i; k < 1 + i; k++)
        {
            matrix[i][k] = random_numbers[index++];
        }
    }
}
```

make an array (a `std::vector` is perfect for that) with the correct number of values in the pyramid (for 9 cols you have 9 values in the last row, 7 above that, 5 above the 7, 3 above the 5 and 1 above the 3, so 9+7+5+3+1), fill it with random numbers, sort it and then use these values instead of random numbers.

In your `del` function you forgot to use `delete[] matrix[i];` instead of `delete matrix[i];`. A `new[]` needs a `delete[]`.

Running example: https://godbolt.org/z/o34vncYor